Why $ n$ in $x^{-n}$ must be an integer?
According to https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation
the $x^{-n} = \frac{1}{x^n}$ is defined only if $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $x \in \mathbb{R}$, $x \neq 0$. But why $n$ can't be also an rational number?

Notice I edited your question to improve the formatting. It is strongly advised that you use Mathjax to format your questions on this site - it's like LaTeX for the web. I edited your question this time since you are new, but in future, please format the question yourself. See here for a quick guide: MathJax tutorial

thanks :) I wrote this on mobile during Biology lesson otherwise I would use latex :D

That's not really an excuse. Mobile also allows you to write backlashes and curly braces which is all you need.

You're totally right, my bad. Anyways, thanks for editing it :)

Short answer: Because $(-1)^\frac12$ does not exist in the reals.

Slightly longer answer: Because $(-1)\frac12$ is hard to define. In general, $a^\frac12$ can be defined as the solution to the equation $x^2=a$, but that equation has two solutions.
As long as $a$ is positive, only one of the solutions to $x^2=a$ is a positive real number, so we can get away with saying that $a^\frac12$ is the positive of the two solutions. In case of $a<0$, the solutions are imaginary, so you can no longer say which is positive and which negative.
It gets worse for $a^\frac1n$ for $n\geq 3$, when there are even more solutions to $x^n=a$, and therefore it's even harder to pick just one. Again, so long as $a>0$, only one of the solutions is a positive real number so we can pick that one, but if $a<0$, no obvious candidate emerges.

Longest answer: It gets very complicated, as in general, you could say that $a^x=e^{\ln a^x} = e^{x\cdot \ln a}$, but the question of what a logarithm of a negative number is can again be an entire topic onto itself.

The notation $x^n$ is overloaded and can refer to any of several related but not identical concepts:

Repeated multiplication of $x$ by itself, when $n$ is a natural number;
When $x$ is real and $n = \frac{a}{b}$ is rational, the $a$th power of the $b$th principal root of $x$: $(\sqrt[b]{x})^a$;
A smooth function from positive real numbers and real exponents to real numbers, $x^n = \exp(n \log x)$;
The restriction of the complex function $z^n: \mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$, given by $z^n = \exp(n \log z)$ (where $\log z$ is the principal value of the complex logarithm) to real values of $z$.

Definitions 2--4 all agree with each other when $x$ is positive, but not when $x$ is negative. For instance $(-1)^{\frac{1}{3}}$ is $-1$ according to definition 2; undefined according to definition 3; and $\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}i$ according to definition 4. Each of the above definitions have their pros and cons and can be useful in different contexts. For example, when doing everyday arithmetic it is useful to be able to take rational powers of negative numbers using definition 2; when doing calculus and you need your functions to be continuous and/or differentiable, definitions 3 and 4 become more useful.
There is nothing wrong per se with writing $x^{-n}$ when $n$ is rational, as long as it's clear what you mean by that notation (particularly if $x$ is negative). In fact expressions such as $x^{-1/2}$ are very common both in mathematics and in applications.
